# Merging PDFs in python using convertapi

Tags: python, pdf, merge, convertapi

I'm trying to use the module [convertapi](https://www.convertapi.com/) to merge PDFs in Python3.8. I've tried multiple ways but I'm unable to figure out the origin of the returned error. Here is my function:

```
def merger(output_path, input_paths):

    dictFiles = {}
    for i,path in enumerate(input_paths):
        dictFiles[f'File[{i}]'] = path

    convertapi.api_secret = 'my-api-secret'
    result = convertapi.convert('merge', dictFiles, from_format = 'pdf')
    result.save_files(output_path)
```

And here is the error that is returned:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\client.py", line 46, in handle_response
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: 
https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/merge?Secret=my-api-secret

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "D:\Desktop\merger.py", line 46, in merger
    result = convertapi.convert('merge', dictFiles, from_format = 'pdf')
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\api.py", line 7, in convert
    return task.run()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\task.py", line 26, in run
    response = convertapi.client.post(path, params, timeout = timeout)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\client.py", line 16, in post
    return self.handle_response(r)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\client.py", line 49, in handle_response
    raise ApiError(r.json())
convertapi.exceptions.ApiError: Parameter validation error. Code: 4000. {'Files': ['Files array item 
count must be greater than 0.']}
```

I am suspecting the error to come from the fact that the dict is created before the merging because when entering directly the dictionary in the `covertapi.convert()`, I'm not getting the same error:

```
def merger(output_path, input_paths):
    convertapi.api_secret = 'my-api-secret'
    convertapi.convert('merge', {
        'Files[0]': 'path/to/file1.pdf',
        'Files[1]': 'path/to/file2.pdf'
    }, from_format = 'pdf').save_files(output_path)
```

Here a different error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\client.py", line 46, in handle_response
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url:         
https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/merge?Secret=my-api-secret

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "D:\Desktop\merger.py", line 50, in merger
    convertapi.convert('merge', {
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\api.py", line 7, in convert
    return task.run()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\task.py", line 26, in run
    response = convertapi.client.post(path, params, timeout = timeout)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\client.py", line 16, in post
    return self.handle_response(r)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\convertapi\client.py", line 49, in handle_response
    raise ApiError(r.json())
convertapi.exceptions.ApiError: Unable to download remote file. Code: 5007.
```

Note that here I'm note using PyPDF2 to merge files because I'm having some errors when the file contains some specific characters (mostly chinese characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will go to https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-merge and scroll down you easily will find snippet builder and amount all programming snippets you will find Python one.

```
convertapi.api_secret = 'Your_secret'
convertapi.convert('merge', {
    'Files[0]': '/path/to/dpa.pdf',
    'Files[1]': '/path/to/sample.pdf'
}, from_format = 'pdf').save_files('/path/to/dir')
```

And if you take some time to analyze snippet you will find that plural is used for Files array and not singular like in your code.

```
def merger(output_path, input_paths):

    dictFiles = {}
    for i,path in enumerate(input_paths):
        dictFiles[f'File[{i}]'] = path

    convertapi.api_secret = 'my-api-secret'
    result = convertapi.convert('merge', dictFiles, from_format = 'pdf')
    result.save_files(output_path)

convertapi.exceptions.ApiError: Parameter validation error. Code: 4000. {'Files': ['Files array item 
count must be greater than 0.']}
```

As for the second error, you didn't provide the code so I can't help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so blind!